# Layered SVG interactivity - JavaScript library

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, html5-canvas

[image: Illustration]

Say I have an illustration like this and I want to add interactivity in the browser when a user hovers or clicks on an individual person in the picture. Is there a good Javascript library that will allow for importing of SVG or even PSD with layers and convert them into individual objects in the browser? Or possibly HTML5 canvas.

Comment: Modern browsers support (inline) svg including event handlers such as hovering over or clicking on shapes.

Comment: If it is an image I'd go for an image my myself. That is exactly what they were made for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While questions asking for libraries usually are not a good fit for SO due to the opinionated nature of their answers, you might actually solve this problem with native HTML5 SVG support + CSS + JavaScript event handlers and no library at all:

```js
document.getElementById("waldo").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("Waldo clicked")
});
```

```css
svg #waldo:hover {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
Hover over and click the blue box with id = waldo:
<svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="green" />
  <rect id="waldo" x="70" y="70" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" />
  <rect x="160" y="30" width="100" height="100" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
```

PS: I found Waldo: [image: Waldo]